# Calling simple methods in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I just want to know how to call methods/functions in java. Can you please help me with this?

So here's my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyFirstProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        hello();
    }

    static void hello(int a, int b) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total;
        System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
        b = scan.nextInt();

        total = a + b;

        System.out.println("The total is: " + total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 clicks away, here's a pictured answer - http://www.wikihow.com/Call-a-Method-in-Java

In your code what you're actually missing is passing the required parameters - the values for `a` and `b`. The call should actually look like `MyFirstProject.hello(2, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

You make the method hello static for the class MyFirstProject so it has connotations -> [Explanation](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-static-method-program).

But the problem here is that you are missing to pass parameters to the method:

```
int example_arg_one = 3;
int example_arg_two = 5;

MyFirstProject.hello(example_arg_one,example_arg_two);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your method `hello(int a, int b)` has a parameter of two integers, you need to give it the integers when calling it in order for it to work. But that also doesn't make sense since you have a Scanner which defines your integers in your method. Just remove the parameters of your method and your code should work.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    hello();
}

static void hello() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total;
    System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
    int b = scan.nextInt();

    total = a + b;


    System.out.println("The total is: " + total);
}
```

Regarding how to call methods, you're doing it right. Just do not neglect your parameter, if your method has one you have to give it one. If you do not know what a parameter is, it is the hello **(int a, int b)**. Your method is expecting you to give it two integers, because that is how you defined your method, you defined it to take two integers. If you want to call it using the parameter, call it in your main and give it two integers, for example `hello(1, 2)`

**Note:** If you want to do that you have to remove the scan.nextInt() from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass two parameters a and b into method hello.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    hello(a,b);
}
```